# WPF UserControl Event Handler Memory Loss

Tags: wpf, events, controls

I have a form which references a UserControl

```
<Label Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="2" >Item Category</Label>
<PO:ItemCategorySelector Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="3" x:Name="usrItemCategoryId" SelectedValueChanged="usrItemCategoryId_SelectedValueChanged"
                               IsOptional="True"  Width="250" />
```

The event is defined as follows:

```
   #region events
    public delegate void SelectedValueChangedDelegate(object sender, SelectedValueChangedEventArgs e);
    protected event SelectedValueChangedDelegate _SelectedValueChanged;
    public event SelectedValueChangedDelegate SelectedValueChanged
    {
        add
        {
            if (this._SelectedValueChanged == null)
                this._SelectedValueChanged += value;
        }
        remove
        {
            if (this._SelectedValueChanged != null)
                this._SelectedValueChanged -= value;
        }
    }

protected void RaiseSelectedValueChanged(modItemCategory pItemCategory)
{
    if (this._SelectedValueChanged != null)
    {
        var evt = new SelectedValueChangedEventArgs(pItemCategory);
        this._SelectedValueChanged(this, evt);
    }
}
```

## endregion

I have put break points on the Add and Remove properties of the event.
When the form loads the Add property triggers.
When I close the form the Remove property never triggers.
This must contribute to the memory leaks I am finding.
Surely if a control is defined in XAML and it links in the event handler it should be responsible for removing that handler? If not how would you set about removing it?

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

> Surely if a control is defined in XAML and it links in the event handler it should be responsible for removing that handler?

No, there is no one unsubscribing from the event handler for you.

But this shouldn't be an issue as long as the publisher of the event (the `ItemCategorySelector`) and the subscriber of the event (the `UserControl`) have equal lifetimes.

The `ItemCategorySelector` instance will be eligible for garbage collection as soon as the parent `UserControl` instance is. So if you are experiencing any memory leaks, it is probably not because of this event handler.

> If not how would you set about removing it?

You could for example handle the `Unloaded` event and remove the event handler using the -= syntax:

```
private void usrItemCategoryId_Unloaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    usrItemCategoryId.SelectedValueChanged -= usrItemCategoryId_SelectedValueChanged;
}
```